# Does $f(x,y)= Ax^2+ 2Bxy+ Cy^2+2 Dx+2Ey+F, A>0, B^2<AC$ attain a minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Re-writing gives: $f(x,y)=  \left(\sqrt A x+ \frac B{\sqrt A} y\right)^2+\left(C- B^2/A\right) y^2 +2Dx+2Ey+F$

Solving $f_x=f_y=0$ for extrema yields $(x_1,y_1)$. Specifically, $x_1=-\frac{BE+DC}{AC-B^2},y_1=\frac{DB+AE}{AC-B^2}$.

Partial derivatives of second order are: $f_{xx}=2A, f_{xy}=f_{yx}=2B, f_{yy}=2C$. By second order derivative [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_two_variables), since $A>0, AC- B^2>0$, it follows that $(x_1,y_1)$ is local minimum.

Showing that it is indeed a global minimum answers the question in affirmative. Can anyone please suggest how to do that without using too much computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can complete the square.

We have
\begin{align*}
 f(x, y) &= \left(\sqrt A x+ \frac B{\sqrt A} y + \frac{D}{\sqrt A}\right)^2+\left(C- B^2/A\right) \left(y + \frac{AE - BD}{AC - B^2}\right)^2\\[10pt]
 &\qquad  + \frac{ACF - AE^2 - B^2F + 2BDE - CD^2}{AC - B^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Two possible approaches:

(I) Use the [Principal Axis Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20principal%20axis%20theorem%20states,the%20square%20from%20elementary%20algebra.).

(II) Check that $f(x,y)\rightarrow +\infty$ along the $y$-axis or any line $y=mx$. This shows that a global minimum exists. Necessarily $f_x=f_y=0$ at any point where the global minimum is achieved. But there is only one such point since $B^2-AC\neq 0.$

Note that $A>0,B^2<AC\Rightarrow C>0$ and $A+2Bm+Cm^2>0$ for any $m$.